# How to close token accounts using @solana/spl-token v: "0.3.8" and wallet adapter

Tags: spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, transaction

I'm trying to close token accounts using the wallet adapter,I'm facing the following issues

```
  const closeAcc = async (tokenpubkey: PublicKey) => {
    if (wallet.publicKey) {
      let tx = new Transaction().add(
        createCloseAccountInstruction(
          tokenpubkey, // token account which you want to close
          wallet.publicKey, // destination
          wallet.publicKey // owner of token account
        )
      );

      if (wallet && wallet.signTransaction) {
        let blockhash = (await connection.getLatestBlockhash('finalized')).blockhash;
        tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
        tx.feePayer = wallet.publicKey;
        let signature = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx,connection);
        await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "processed");
      }
    }
  };
```

Issue 1) On mainnet it works fine, but on devnet I get this error "Transaction expired. You waited too long to approve the transaction and it expire" and "Error processing instruction 0: INvalid account data for instruction"

Issue 2) connection.confirmTransaction shows up as deprecated, what is the right thing to use now?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here is how I resolved these

1. Did not realise I have to first switch networks inside of phantom wallet if I want to work with devnet apps
2. This is the proper way

````
    if (wallet.publicKey) {
      const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
      let tx = new Transaction(latestBlockhash).add(
        createCloseAccountInstruction(
          tokenpubkey, // token account which you want to close
          wallet.publicKey, // destination
          wallet.publicKey // owner of token account
        )
      );

      if (wallet && wallet.signTransaction) {
        const signature = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx, connection);
        await connection.confirmTransaction({
          ...latestBlockhash,
          signature,
        });
      }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 1):

For issue 1, be sure that `tokenpubkey` also exists on devnet. Most likely you're mixing devnet and mainnet connections.

For issue 2, the deprecation notice at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/6524b01189cd4917da62fe78a33fef58bd692986/packages/library-legacy/src/connection.ts#L3711 says exactly what to do:

```
  /** @deprecated Instead, call `confirmTransaction` and pass in {@link TransactionConfirmationStrategy} */
```